# Can I distribute a C++ library with dependencies as a Docker image?

Tags: c++, docker, package, shared-libraries, software-distribution

If I understand correctly, Docker containers **can encapsulate all the dependencies** and allow to distribute executables in a very portable way.

But also (if I understand correctly), they **are isolated from the rest of the applications** which are not inside the container.

So, my question is: if I provide a Docker image that will encapsulate all the dependencies for a C++ library (and the library itself), **will normal (non-containerized) applications be able to use the library?** If not, what if I also create Docker images for these applications?

(What I have in mind is an open-source, scientific C++ library, which relies on several other large and sometimes not-so-common libraries. One of them is e.g. Boost, which needs to be a recent version. Other dependencies are usually not provided in Linux distributions.)

Comment: This is a somewhat broad subject.  But in a nutshell, Docker is used as a way to package self-contained **processes** (or in some cases, data volumes).  It doesn't obviously lend itself to packaging libraries, although I imagine it would be possible to subvert it to do so.

Comment: Let me add that I have seen Docker used to distribute e.g. [OpenFOAM](https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-linux/). OpenFOAM is both a collection of executables, as well as libraries. So I was wondering if I can also use libraries this way. I will leave the question open for a bit longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you distribute a library as a Docker container, only applications inside the container will be able to use it (unless someone bothers to take your library out of the container and use it normally).

Additionally, since Docker containers can't be combined, you wouldn't be able to use two "library containers" in the same program.